# angular js use checkbox model to store array

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, model

In Angular one checkbox  is linked with one model.
But in practice i want one model to store array of checked values from several checkboxes.

There is someone who got this problem and have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a directive for that - this is one solution http://msieurtoph.github.io/angular-checkboxes/